# How to enable CXF pretty print logging on the server side in SOAP?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf

I have a `soap` service with `cxf` and would like to enable the default logging with pretty print by annotations. How could I do this?

```
@WebService
@Features(features = "org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature") //how pretty print?
public class MySoapService {

}
```

It should be a annotation equivalent to the following xml config:

```
<jaxws:endpoint implementor="de.MySoapService" address="/MySoapService">
    <jaxws:features>
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature">
            <property name="prettyLogging" value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </jaxws:features>
</jaxws:endpoint>
```

Comment: Did you attempt to create your own feature to solve this?

Comment: When I have been implementing client based on Apache CXF and Spring boot 2.1.6.RELEASE noticed that analogous configuration to above won't work if there is cxf:bus configured as well. Also didn't manage to enable prettyLogging via bus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem by creating a very simple class that extends `LoggingFeature` and set `prettylogging` to `true`:

```
public class PrettyLoggingFeature extends LoggingFeature{

    public PrettyLoggingFeature(){
        super.setPrettyLogging(true);
    }
}
```

After that, I was able to use this class on features.